# SSIS Re-Order Column Headings in CSV

Tags: csv, ssis, export, columnheader

I have a SSIS Package that Imports data from multiple CSV files into a multiple tables within a SQL database, I then do a SQL query to get the data I need and export into a csv file.

My issue is: I need to re-order the columns and I can't do this within the connection manager.

I can add new fields to the csv within the connection manager and can 'add before' or 'add after' to get the positioning correct but I cannot re-order the existing ones.

Is this possible within SSIS ? I have tried looking around but cannot see how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

i figured this out. I deleted the columns from the connections manager and re added them where I wanted them positioned. I then went into the flat file destination and re mapped the headings with correct field.